# No results from Join in Database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

i want to join two tables to get the Doctors name instead of the ID

```
SELECT Doctors.doct_name,
       Shifts.shift_date,
       Shifts.shift_day,
       Shifts.shift_start,
       Shifts.shift_end
  FROM SHIFTS 
  JOIN Doctors ON Doctors.doct_id = Shifts.doct_id
```

the Column are shown but without any Results ,, no data from the database ?

Comment: Check the `SHIFTS` table - my guess is you don't have any `doct_id` values that match those in `DOCTORS.doct_id`.

Comment: Is there any data in either of those tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your query looks ok.

try two seperate queries to validate the basic data:

```
select * from Doctors order by doct_id;
```

and

```
select * from Shifts order by doct_id;
```

see if you can manually spot the data issue:

Comment: +1 for a sane answer.  The first step the OP ought to do is figure out what data s/he has.

Answer (score 1):

Try a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT Doctors.doct_name,Shifts.shift_date,Shifts.shift_day,Shifts.shift_start,Shifts.shift_end
  FROM SHIFTS 
  LEFT JOIN Doctors ON Doctors.doct_id = Shifts.doct_id
```

Comment: That'll just show SHIFT values - based on the info provided, I'd expect the `DOCTORS` references to all be NULL.

Comment: Still the same problem after i checked ?

Comment: My guess was that at least forcing the join to left, would give a clear view of the data in the database and that would help the OP further.

Comment: @Omneya - Then it really depends on the data and it will be very difficult to help you further without at least a sample of the contents of these tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try using left join and also try using Where clause with an id to check if there is really Doctors exist in both tables

```
SELECT Doctors.doct_name,Shifts.shift_date,Shifts.shift_day,Shifts.shift_start,Shifts.shift_end
```

FROM SHIFTS 
  LEFT JOIN Doctors ON Doctors.doct_id = Shifts.doct_id

OR

```
SELECT Doctors.doct_name,Shifts.shift_date,Shifts.shift_day,Shifts.shift_start,Shifts.shift_end
```

FROM SHIFTS 
  LEFT JOIN Doctors ON Doctors.doct_id = Shifts.doct_id 
  WHERE Doctors.doct_id = [insert doctors id here - doctors_id]